# Use recyclerview in portrait and table layout in landscape

Tags: android

I have two activities one with a recyclerview and one with a tableview.
I want to use the recyclerview in portrait and the tablview in the landscape orientation. As far as the xml code goes a landscape view can be easily set up so I can show the table layout but how do I specify the code to populate the tableview??

I have spent hours to find how to do so with no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `layout` file for landscape in `layout-land` folder. And the `layout` file for portrait in `layout` folder itself.

Now, whenever the device is in landscape then the `layout` file from `layout-land` folder will be rendered, else `layout` file from `layout` folder would be rendered.

So, add the `RecyclerView` in the `layout/activity_name.xml` file and put `TableView` in the `layout-land/activity_name.xml` file. This will solve your problem.

*Note:*

- `layout-land` folder is not already present in the project, you've to explicitly create that.
- Both the folders `layout` and `layout-land` must be the sub-folder of `res`. Like this:

  ```
  /* Some files here */

  - res
  ---- - layout
  ---- ---- activity_name.xml
  ---- - layout-land
  ---- ---- activity_name.xml
  ---- + drawable

  /* Some files here */
  ```

Comment: @Zlytherin I am not sure how to use the java code.... I mean the findviewby id and all... could you link me an example?

Comment: @PembaTamang you can check if `TableView` is null of not by using `findViewById` if that returns null then that mean the phone is in portrait and else the phone is in landscape. So you can do that by `if / else`. Now I think you can easily do that. Now your whole code can be in if else statement. Get this?