# Android RecyclerViewAdapter items wrong width after rotating back to portrait and calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a view that has an `exoplayer` as its background and `RecyclerView` that will display comments on top of the playing video.

I had to stop my activity form recreating the view on each rotation, since it was stopping and restarting the video, so I'm managing the configuration changes manually, only for this Activity in my app.

I'm using a ConstraintLayout for this activity, and the comments RecyclerView needs to be half of the screen's height, and full width, when the device is in portrait, and half of the screen's width and full height, when the device is in landscape.

I've achieved this using `ConstraintSet` and setting my `RecyclerView`'s constraints in my `onConfigurationChanged`.

The only problem I'm facing is that after the device is rotatetd to landscape and then back to portrait and `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, the visible cells of the recycler view have a very weird width, even smaller than the one they had on landscape. If I scroll up or down, the widths get fixed, as the items are being recycled.

I tried calling `notifyDatatSetChanged()` after the rotation, which did not seem to fix my problem. I've also tried setting the adapter and layoutManager to null and back to their real values but the cells are still not redrawn to match their correct width. Using the layout inspector, I can see that the item's width is set to match parent, but the visible cells just don't respect that.

Does anyone have any idea on whats going on here and how to redraw the cells so they have the correct width? Thank you for your time.

[image: Screenshot from the Layout inspector]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a layout-land folder for your landscape layouts.

Whenever the device is in landscape then the layout file from layout-land folder will be rendered, else layout file from layout folder would be rendered.

In conclusion , add the RecyclerView item in the layout/your_name.xml file and put your layout in the layout-land/your_name.xml file. I think this should solve your problem. At the end your layout organization should be like this

```
- res
 - layout
  ---- your_name.xml
 - layout-land
  ---- your_name.xml
```

When you are in portrait mode your activity will use layout when land your activity will use layout land. There is a similar problem like yours and solving here [Use recyclerview in portrait and table layout in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264446/use-recyclerview-in-portrait-and-table-layout-in-landscape)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is actually what I'm trying to avoid (different layouts for each orientation), plus I'm pretty sure this wouldn't work since I have enabled `android:configChanges = "orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"` to keep the video player running when the device is rotated, instead of it getting re-created.